# What are some good sites for listening to podcasts?

Tags: webapp-rec, audio

Currently I use Google Listen on Android for listening to podcast, but is there a good webapp for finding new podcast and listening to them?

Today I miss the option to sync with desktop and track which podcast I have listened to. Also finding new interesting podcasts related to politics and technology can be difficult. Therefore a webapp, perhaps with an android client would be very interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spokenword.org](http://www.spokenword.org/) has some interesting properties for podcast aggregation. There is also a fair number of good feeds to find in the catalog.

Answer (score 2):

Google Listen syncs with Google Reader and creates a special folder called "Listen Subscriptions". You can add podcast feeds to that folder and it will also end up in your Listen on your Android.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google has since deprecated Listen. However, some other Android apps do sync with, or import from, Google Reader. http://www.androidauthority.com/google-kills-google-apps-for-teams-google-listen-and-google-video-for-business-105725/

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend http://huffduffer.com/

It is a site that offers a feature which is the ability to make your own stream of podcasts. Any time you see a single episode of something you would like to listen to you can Huffduff it which adds it to a podcast stream that you can subscribe to.

While this doesn't sound like it answers your question the interesting side feature is that you can easily explore who else huffduffed the shows you liked and it will help you find shows that you are likely to like.

If you can get over the crazy name that is.

Comment: Ah, the name isn't that crazy. It comes from HF/DF - see http://huffduffer.com/about and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huff-Duff

Answer (score 1):

http://www.podcastalley.com/ is the big pod index.

```
Site Statistics
Podcasts: 84,781
Comments: 243,287
Episodes:  5,701,159
```

Comment: Thanks Evan. Great number of sites there, but I'm also looking for quality.